# Error Auto Scroll 'minimum' and 'maximum' c# datagridview winform

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

```
        try
        {
            string MyConnectionsss = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog = 'svms';username=svms;password=svms2016CPU";
            string Query = "select * from userinformation";
            MySqlConnection MyConn2sss = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionsss);
            MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, MyConn2sss);
            MySqlDataAdapter MyAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            MyAdapter.SelectCommand = MyCommand2;
            DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
            MyAdapter.Fill(dTable);
            metroGrid1.DataSource = dTable;
            metroGrid1.PerformLayout();
            metroGrid1.Columns["UserPassword"].Visible = false;     
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MetroMessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "MySQL says:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
```

The error shows up if I put this code "metroGrid1.Columns["UserPassword"].Visible = false;" I already tried metroGrid1.PerformLayout(); at the scroll event. Still doesn't work. Hope someone could please help. Thanks!

Comment: What's the error?  And what does this have to do with scrolling?  Maybe your table doesn't have a UserPassword field.

Comment: Here's the Error: Value of '5' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'.
Of course I have UserPassword field. I don't get it.. On my other forms, if I hide a field they work fine.

Comment: Nah, just ignore this! I deleted the old grid, and I just created another one. And it works fine now. Maybe I wrongly manipulated somewhere in the properties. Lol. Thanks btw. I'm just maybe kinda sleepy. haha!

Comment: There should be a delete link by the tags.